# The length of an quarter outer circle given an inner quarter circle of known length unknown radius.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

This question was asked by someone on reddit.  He wants to know the length, $K$, that a beam must be to surround a quarter circle segment of length $L$ at a distance $d$.

This is his drawing. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dLlq.jpg

In the drawing the length of the inner quarter circle is $L$ and $d$ is the distance between the inner and outer quarter circle.

The formula I derived is $$K= \frac{\pi d}{2} + L$$

But I'm not sure. I have a tendency to make trivial mistakes. I also think there might be an easier or more elegant way to derive this.

I calculated the radius of the inner circle using $C/2r = \pi$ with $C=4L$ and  $L=\frac{(r\pi)}{2}$ so $r=\frac{2L}{\pi}$. Then I added $d$ to that to get the radius of the outer circle $R=r+d$ and used $\frac{C}{2R}=\pi$ with $C=4K$ and $K=\frac{R\pi}{2}$ to calculate $K$.

This is my calculation:

Assuming that the curved part is a quarter circle then from $\frac{C}{D} = \frac{C}{2r}= \pi$

and dividing by $4$ because you are dealing with a quarter circle and taking the length of the curved part equal to $L (C=4L)$

Then

$$\frac{L}{r} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

and solve for $r$ to get the radius of the inner circle.

$$\frac{1}{r} = \frac{\pi}{2L}$$

$r=\frac{2L}{\pi}$

Then $r+d=R$

where $R$ is the radius of the outer circle

Then reapply the formula $\frac{L}{r} = \frac{\pi}{2}$ for the outer curved part with unknown length $K$. (So replace $L$ with $K$ and $r$ with $R=r+d= \frac{2L}{\pi} + d$)

$$\frac{K}{R}= \frac{\pi}{2}$$ where $R= d+r = d+\frac{2L}{\pi}$

Solve for $K$.

$$K=\frac{R\pi}{2} =\left(d+\frac{2L}{\pi}\right)\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\left(\frac{d\pi}{2}\right) +L$$

$$=\frac{d\pi}{2} + L$$

Comment: This may be the first ever question to have both the algebra-precalculus and differential-geometry tag.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: There might be a more advanced differential geometry approach. I'm in an unusual position because I actually studied differential geometry at one time, but I  haven't been doing much math in the last few years. When I first saw the problem I thought "great I can use some differential geometry" but that seemed like overkill. It would still be neat if someone else did it.

Comment: I'm assuming, contrary to what the diagram suggests, that the inner radius is $L$.

Comment: Yes. The inner radius is L. The diagram could be better. I didn't draw it.

Comment: Er, sorry, not "radius" but "length of inner quarter circle".

Comment: That's what I meant too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly (please let me know if I don't), this has to do with the old question about how far a (hypothetical) rubber band around the Earth would have to be stretched in order to raise it above the Earth by a meter.

The intuitive notion that it takes quite a bit of stretching (because the Earth is so large, by normal standards) is belied by the reasoning that you've only increased the radius by 1 meter, so the circumference is increased by only $2\pi$ meters.

One can generalize this slightly by allowing any angle.  If the arc subtends $\theta$ radians, then increasing the radius by $d$ increases the length of the arc by $\theta d$.

Comment: So is there an easier way to do it?  I feel like I made this calculation way more tedious than it had to be.  I suppose I could redo it for the full circle rather than the quarter circle.

Comment: Sure.  There are $\theta = \pi/2$ radians in a right angle, so the added distance is $\theta d = \pi d/2$.